# MySQL multiple inner joins, unions and where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

Edit to my original post. After using LEFT join here's how the query looks.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS fname, lname, desig, company, region, state, country, add_uid, contacts.`id` as id
        FROM contacts

         LEFT JOIN contact_art_collections ON contact_art_collections.contact_id = contacts.id
         AND (
             contact_art_collections.name LIKE '%singapore%'
             OR contact_art_collections.email LIKE '%singapore%'
             OR contact_art_collections.ph1_no LIKE '%singapore%'
             OR contact_art_collections.ph1_desc LIKE '%singapore%'
             OR contact_art_collections.ph2_no LIKE '%singapore%'
             OR contact_art_collections.ph2_desc LIKE '%singapore%'
             OR contact_art_collections.web LIKE '%singapore%'
             OR contact_art_collections.address LIKE '%singapore%'
         )

 LEFT JOIN contact_offices ON contact_offices.contact_id = contacts.id
 AND(
    contact_offices.off_address LIKE '%singapore%'
    OR contact_offices.off_phone1 LIKE '%singapore%'
    OR contact_offices.off_phone1_desc LIKE '%singapore%'
    OR contact_offices.off_phone2 LIKE '%singapore%'
    OR contact_offices.off_phone2_desc LIKE '%singapore%'
    OR contact_offices.off_phone3 LIKE '%singapore%'
    OR contact_offices.off_phone3_desc LIKE '%singapore%'
    OR contact_offices.off_city LIKE '%singapore%'
    OR contact_offices.off_zip LIKE '%singapore%'
    OR contact_offices.off_state LIKE '%singapore%'
    OR contact_offices.off_region LIKE '%singapore%'
    OR contact_offices.off_country LIKE '%singapore%'
 )

 LEFT JOIN contact_professional_details ON contact_professional_details.contact_id = contacts.id
 AND(
    contact_professional_details.pd_desig LIKE '%singapore%'
    OR contact_professional_details.pd_comp LIKE '%singapore%'
    OR contact_professional_details.pd_regd_comp LIKE '%singapore%'
 )

 LEFT JOIN contact_address ON contact_address.contact_id = contacts.id
 AND(
    contact_address.hmadd LIKE '%singapore%'
    OR contact_address.hmcity LIKE '%singapore%'
    OR contact_address.hmzip LIKE '%singapore%'
    OR contact_address.hmstate LIKE '%singapore%'
    OR contact_address.hmregion LIKE '%singapore%'
    OR contact_address.hmcountry LIKE '%singapore%'
 )

 LEFT JOIN contact_emails ON contact_emails.contact_id = contacts.id
 AND(
     contact_emails.email LIKE '%singapore%'
 )

 LEFT JOIN assistant_emails ON assistant_emails.contact_id = contacts.id
 AND(
     assistant_emails.email LIKE '%singapore%'
 )

 LEFT JOIN contact_fax ON contact_fax.contact_id = contacts.id
 AND(
    contact_fax.fax LIKE '%singapore%'
 )

 LEFT JOIN contact_phones ON contact_phones.contact_id = contacts.id
 AND(
     contact_phones.ph_no LIKE '%singapore%'
     OR contact_phones.ph_desc LIKE '%singapore%' 
 )

 LEFT JOIN assistant_phones ON assistant_phones.contact_id = contacts.id
 AND(
     assistant_phones.ph_no LIKE '%singapore%' 
     OR assistant_phones.ph_desc LIKE '%singapore%' 
 )

 LEFT JOIN contact_websites ON contact_websites.contact_id = contacts.id
 AND(
     contact_websites.web LIKE '%singapore%'
 )

        WHERE ( contacts.`title` LIKE '%singapore%' OR 
contacts.`fname` LIKE '%singapore%' OR 
contacts.`lname` LIKE '%singapore%' OR 
contacts.`full_name` LIKE '%singapore%' OR 
contacts.`desig` LIKE '%singapore%' OR 
contacts.`company` LIKE '%singapore%' OR 
contacts.`regd_company` LIKE '%singapore%' OR 
contacts.`remarks` LIKE '%singapore%' OR 
contacts.`artstage_contact` LIKE '%singapore%' OR 
contacts.`status` LIKE '%singapore%' OR 
contacts.`referred_by_name` LIKE '%singapore%' OR 
contacts.`vip_tier` LIKE '%singapore%' OR 
contacts.`vip_coll_tier` LIKE '%singapore%' OR 
contacts.`vip_influencer` LIKE '%singapore%' OR 
contacts.`vip_seniority` LIKE '%singapore%' OR 
contacts.`vip_as_fname` LIKE '%singapore%' OR 
contacts.`vip_as_lname` LIKE '%singapore%' OR 
contacts.`vip_as_email` LIKE '%singapore%' OR 
contacts.`vip_as_ph` LIKE '%singapore%' OR 
contacts.`vip_class_art_coll` LIKE '%singapore%' OR 
contacts.`vip_med_art_coll` LIKE '%singapore%' OR 
contacts.`vip_geo_int` LIKE '%singapore%' OR 
contacts.`media_art_media` LIKE '%singapore%' OR 
contacts.`media_freq` LIKE '%singapore%' OR 
contacts.`exb_waitlist` LIKE '%singapore%' OR 
contacts.`exb_blacklist` LIKE '%singapore%' OR 
contacts.`exb_greylist` LIKE '%singapore%' OR 
contacts.`exb_grade` LIKE '%singapore%' OR 
contacts.`exb_art_fairs` LIKE '%singapore%' OR 
contacts.`exb_exhibitor_applicant` LIKE '%singapore%' ) 

        ORDER BY  fname
                    asc
        LIMIT 0, 50
```

Takes 42 seoncds to execute which is a lot of time. All LIKE fields used here have indexes created already. Will try using the temprary table next.

Comment: Do you see anything if you drop all WHERE clauses? If yes, start adding them block by block and see at which point it goes wrong. If not, then it would mean that joining all the tables on common fields isn't possible.

Comment: Other than what @Ashalynd suggested, try changing `inner join` to `left join` and see if you get any results.

Comment: one or more of the tables have no match with the original CONTACTS table: since you're using INNER JOIN 's , this is going to skip the results. Consider using LEFT JOIN for the one or ones that are making this skipping the results.

Comment: Why are all sugesting what I already answer a few minuts ago?

Comment: @Horaciux, LOL .. put a copyright to your answer then.

Comment: If there's a lot of data in those tables later on - then a query like this with `LIKE '%<searchterm>%'` on so many columns will certainly not performing well ...

Comment: Will try using LEFT join and if that does not work either then do you think creating a temporary table, search each table individually for matches for the keyword using like '%XX%', adding the contact id in the temp table and at the end joining it with the contacts master table is a good idea?

Comment: Have edited my original post with LEFT JOIN. But takes super long to execute.

Comment: @Kunal any `like '%text%'` condition will take time. But how to solve this is other question. I think I answered your primary question, could you formally accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you are using `INNER JOIN` which indicates that only id having rows in all tables will bring data even before applying the WHERE filter.

I would use `LEFT JOIN` and see. Then apply WHERE conditions

Comment: All conditions of tables that are outer joined have to go into the ON clause, else we're back to `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: This seems the most likely explanation.  An id missing a match in any one of the tables is going to be filtered out, even if another row in another table matches.